# I can't get AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor to export a small video

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avassetwriter

This code below will compile and run, but the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor is returning NO when I try to appendBuffer:

Any thoughts as to why?

```
- (void) performCompression
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(480, 320);

    NSString *compressionDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    [self evaluateTrimmers];

    scrubTime = 0.0;
    currentFrameIndex = 0;  

    NSError *error = nil;

    //----initialize compression engine
    self.videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[compressionDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4v",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"RecentFileName"]]]]
                                                 fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                    error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey, nil];
    writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain]; //[[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];


    NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

    adaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                            sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary] retain]; //[[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor alloc] initWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                                                                                                                //sourcePixelBufferAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil]];
    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);

    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    //---
    // insert demo debugging code to write the same image repeated as a movie

    CGImageRef theImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape.png"] CGImage];

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:theImage size:size];
    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];

    for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
    {       
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
        {
            printf("inside for loop %i\n", i);

            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, 20);
            CMTime lastTime = CMTimeMake(i, 20);
            CMTime presentTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, frameTime);

            buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:theImage size:size];
            if (![adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime])
                NSLog(@"FAIL");
            CVBufferRelease(buffer);
        }
        else {
            printf("error\n");
            i--;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"outside for loop");

    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];
}

- (CVPixelBufferRef )pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image size:(CGSize)size
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey, 
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey, nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width, size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (CFDictionaryRef) options, &pxbuffer);
    // CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);  

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width, size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    NSParameterAssert(context);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it all working!

The problem I found was because of an apple bug: try using the same technique but with blocks and not a while loop:

```
[writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue usingBlock:^{
    while ([writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
    {
        if(++frame >= 120)
        {
            [writerInput markAsFinished];
            [videoWriter finishWriting];
            [videoWriter release];
            break;
        }

        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:theImage size:size];
        if (buffer)
        {
            if(![adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frame, 20)])
                NSLog(@"FAIL");
            else
                NSLog(@"Success:%d", frame);
            CFRelease(buffer);
        }
    }
}];
```

Here is the sample code link: git@github.com:RudyAramayo/AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorSample.git

Here is the code you need:

```
- (void) testCompressionSession
{
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(480, 320);


NSString *betaCompressionDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];

NSError *error = nil;

unlink([betaCompressionDirectory UTF8String]);

//----initialize compression engine
AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:betaCompressionDirectory]
                                                       fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
if(error)
    NSLog(@"error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey, nil];
AVAssetWriterInput *writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];

NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];
NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);

if ([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput])
    NSLog(@"I can add this input");
else
    NSLog(@"i can't add this input");

[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

//---
// insert demo debugging code to write the same image repeated as a movie

CGImageRef theImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Lotus.png"] CGImage];

dispatch_queue_t    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
int __block         frame = 0;

[writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue usingBlock:^{
    while ([writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
    {
        if(++frame >= 120)
        {
            [writerInput markAsFinished];
            [videoWriter finishWriting];
            [videoWriter release];
            break;
        }

        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:theImage size:size];
        if (buffer)
        {
            if(![adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frame, 20)])
                NSLog(@"FAIL");
            else
                NSLog(@"Success:%d", frame);
            CFRelease(buffer);
        }
    }
}];

NSLog(@"outside for loop");

}


- (CVPixelBufferRef )pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image size:(CGSize)size
{
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey, 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey, nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width, size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (CFDictionaryRef) options, &pxbuffer);
// CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &pxbuffer);

NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL); 

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width, size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
NSParameterAssert(context);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);

CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

return pxbuffer;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference? It's hard to parse the code and understand.

Comment: sorry, i should have explained that there was a bug in apples stuff... the way that I found a work around was to use the mediaInputQueue.. The mediaInputQueue and requestMediaDataWhenReadOnQueue was the only method that was working at the time...

Comment: I've tried implementing something similar to this, and while it records the view correctly to a quicktime file, it is skewed in the video for some reason. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: You must have changed the coordinates of the CGContextDrawImage command that draws the frame.... or the size of the screen and the size of the images are different... Good luck!

Comment: Edit answer with explanation please, this will help people

Comment: OK i edited the answer... if you goto the link for github.. you can grab the code and hit build... it should run and build a movie on the ios simulator upon startup using frames from the pixel buffer adaptor. Good Luck!